# Html Table Spacing Alignment

Tags: html, html-table, spacing

I'm brand new to html and I was wondering how I could I make a table to display something like this.

"name"_ _ _ _"date"

_ are suppose to be "blank spaces"

I always want "name" aligned on the left and "date" on the right,
independent of what length they are.

I'm completely unfamiliar with html and I need this part for a very small portion of my code.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet, apply `text-align: left` to the cells in the first column and `text-align: right` to those in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

if they're in different columns, the first td do `<td align='left'>` and the second one `<td align='right'>`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical two-column layout. Unordered lists are a good tool for this pattern:

```
<div class="twoCol">
  <ul>
    <li><label>Name</label>Date</li>
    ... more rows ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.twoCol ul, twoCol li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;   
}

.twoCol ul {
    width:200px;   
}   

.twoCol label {
     float:left;
     display:block;  
     width:120px;
     text-align:left;

}

.twoCol li {
     clear:both;
     text-align:right;   
}
```